# Edit UI elements created in fxml from controller class - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have created a text area in fxml and want to append to it when a button is pressed.

How do I access the text area from the controller class so I can append to it?

Comment: We can help if you create a minimal example. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a fx:id to your TextArea in your .fxml file.

```
<TextArea fx:id="myTextArea"/>
<Button fx:id="myButton"/>
```

Go to your controller (java) file and connect it to your fxml:

```
@FXML
private TextArea myTextArea;

@FXML
private Button myButton;
```

Now you can do whatever you want to with your text area.

```
myButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event){
        myTextArea.appendText("Stackoverflow rockz");
    }
}
```

Comment: This works fine for everything except in this case. I define my text area: <TextArea fx:id="txtArea"/>  and then define it in the controller: @FXML private TextArea txtArea; but once I do this I get an error on the fx:id="txtArea" saying "Cannot set javafx.scene.control.TextArea to field 'txtArea' "

Comment: Did you import the correct TextArea class? It seems as your TextArea import in your java doesnt match the one in your FXML. Can you check this. Probably in java you took the java.awt instead of the TextArea from java.fx?

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks